# How can I change the front face colour of a 3D extrusion in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, cs5

I have created a 3D extrusion type in Adobe Photoshop with Repousse and want to change the face / front colour. I have tried using the diffuse option however that only changes the colour for the extrusion not the front face. Has anyone tried changing main object colour, please?

Comment: Just figured out how to do it. Cheers!

Comment: Please either add the method as an answer to your own question for future users or delete the question to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 1):

*Posting D. God's answer here. Copied from the bottom of the question above.*

> Found the answer to this. Posting here for anybody who may come across a similar task.
>
> In the Layers panel, Select the text extrusion layer. Within this layer, just below the Diffuse and Texture you will find the main object layer. Click on this and the layer will open as a separate psd file with a transparent background. Make the changes you want to the object in this file (in my case colour change) and 'Save' it. If you don't 'Save', the change won't reflect in the main file. You can now go back to the extrusion text file and the change will have occurred in there.

-D. God

Comment: *Within this layer, just below the Diffuse and Texture you will find the main object layer.* Where?

Comment: See [Diffuse, Specular, Illumination, and Ambient not showing up in 3D model color options](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/diffuse-specular-illumination-and-ambient-not-showing-up-in-3d-model-color-options/m-p/10863467#M298481).